# How is the UX principle called that the user should know in what state the system is?

Tags: usability, application-state

I know there is a term in UX to describe the situation where the user is aware of the state of the system (or lack of it).

For example when filling a form, after clicking Save, and user has not a way of knowing that the form was actually saved.

Comment: Visibility of System Status www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Comment: @UXLabs that's an answer rather than a comment isn't it? ;)

Comment: @RobbyReindeer yea but im on mobile so i thought i'd hint it and someone else might rewrite it better

Comment: @UXLabs sounds pretty like much what I'm looking for. :) Maybe there are also other terms that refer to this? Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroC this principle is the one you are looking for, although i understand your need to look for other terms, i myself have a different view; it's a bit controversial to disagree with nngroup but i do actually i would have much rathered it being referred as "awareness/evidence of system status" since visibility by definition is bound to vision, does this mean voice-based systems do not apply? And what about the blind users? In regards to the term i think it can be improved but the principle is the same and is the most commonly recognized, if i were you i would not bother complicating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular is "visibility of system status"

NNGroup has a good article that covers everything: [Visibility of System Status](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visibility-system-status/)